# React State Manipulated from Another File Without Reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am following along in a React course on Udemy. In this module, we have a simple task app to demonstrate custom hooks. I've come across a situation where the "task" state is being managed in the App.js file, the "useHttp" custom hook has a function "fetchTasks" which accepts "transformTasks" as a parameter when called inside App.js. The issue I am having is that "tranformTasks" manipulates the "tasks" state inside App.js, but it is actually being called and executed inside the "useHttp" custom hook. Would really love some help understanding the mechanism for how this works. How can the state be manipulated while called from another file without the state being passed in? The code does work as intended. Here's the github link to the full app, and below are the two relevant files: https://github.com/yanichik/react-course/tree/main/full-course/custom-hooks-v2

Here is the App.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks/Tasks";
import NewTask from "./components/NewTask/NewTask";
import useHttp from "./custom-hooks/useHttp";

function App() {
    // manage tasks state here at top level
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    const myUrl = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            url: "https://react-http-104c4-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/tasks.json",
        };
    }, []);

    const { isLoading, error, sendRequest: fetchTasks } = useHttp();

    useEffect(() => {
        // func transforms loaded data to add id (firebase-generated), push to loadedTasks, then
        // push to tasks state
        const transformTasks = (taskObj) => {
            let loadedTasks = [];
            for (const taskKey in taskObj) {
                loadedTasks.push({ id: taskKey, text: taskObj[taskKey].text });
            }
            setTasks(loadedTasks);
        };
        fetchTasks(myUrl, transformTasks);
        // if you add fetchTasks as a dependency this will trigger a re-render each time states
        // are set inside sendRequest (ie fetchTasks) and with each render the custom hook (useHttp)
        // will be recalled to continue the cycle. to avoid this, wrap sendRequest with useCallback
    }, [fetchTasks, myUrl]);

    const addTaskHandler = (task) => {
        setTasks((prevTasks) => prevTasks.concat(task));
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NewTask onEnterTask={addTaskHandler} />
            <Tasks
                items={tasks}
                loading={isLoading}
                error={error}
                onFetch={fetchTasks}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the "useHttp" custom hook:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

// NOTE that useCallback CANNOT be used on the top level function
function useHttp() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const sendRequest = useCallback(async (httpConfig, applyFunction) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError(false);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(httpConfig.url, {
                method: httpConfig.method ? httpConfig.method : "GET",
                headers: httpConfig.headers ? httpConfig.headers : {},
                body: httpConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(httpConfig.body) : null,
            });
            // console.log("response: " + response.method);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Request failed!");
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            
            applyFunction(data);
            // console.log("the formatted task is:" + applyFunction(data));
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message || "Something went wrong!");
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, []);
    return { sendRequest, isLoading, error };
}

export default useHttp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're learning from a decent course. The hook is using a technique called "composition". It knows you'll want to do some processing on the data once it has been fetched and let's you pass in (the `applyFunction` variable) your own snippet of code to do that processing.

Your snippet of code is just a function, but all parties agree on what parameters the function takes. (This is where using typescript helps catch errors.)

So you pass in a function that you write, and your function takes 1 parameter, which you expect will be the data that's downloaded.

The useHttp hook remembers your function and once it has downloaded the data, it calls your function passing in the data.

If you've used some of your own variables within the function you pass to the hook, they get frozen in time ... sort-of. This can of worms is a topic called 'closures' and I'm sure it will come up in the course if it hasn't already.